# define array in excel cell and use that cell in excel array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel cell A1 having cell content {"Q15","R15","S15"}.

How can I use A1 cell in array formula in excel?

I have used this formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('sheet1'!$D$2:$D$838,"<>NA",'sheet1'!$E$2:$E$838,{"Q15","R15","S15"}))
```

the above formula works fine.

but when replaced with A1, it gives 0. And formula becomes

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('sheet1'!$D$2:$D$838,"<>NA",'sheet1'!$E$2:$E$838,A1))
```

How can I use A1 so that the resulting formula contains the actual array?

Comment: With only formulas it would be difficult (but not impossible?).   With a bit of VBA it would be easier:  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/813953-store-retrieve-multiple-values-one-cell.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that Excel is reading `{"Q15","R15","S15"}` from `A1`  as a String (`="{""Q15"",""R15"",""S15""}"`), not as an array.

You *can* get around this using `MID` and `TRIM` to artificially split the string via a `SUMPRODUCT`

```vb
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS('sheet1'!$D$2:$D$838, "<>NA", 'sheet1'!$E$2:$E$838, TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, """,""", REPT(" ", 99)), "{""", ""), """}", ""), 99*ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A, 1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",", ""))))-98, 60))))
```

The "magic" bit here is the rather convoluted line below

TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,""",""",REPT(" ",99)),"{""",""),"""}",""),99*Row(A1:INDEX(A:A,1+Len(A1)-Len(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")))-98,60))

Turns `{"Q15","R15","S15"}` into `Q15`, `R15` and `S15`, separated by 99 spaces.  It then counts how many commas are in `A1`, and (that many times) takes 60 characters (starting at position 1 the first time, then position 100 the second time, then position 199, et cetera) and trims the spaces - this gives an array `{"Q15","R15","S15"}`

So, as Tim Williams says in comments, you might be better off using VBA.  A basic User Defined Function to split the array like this would work:

```vb
Public Function SplitArray(Text As String) As Variant
    'If we error, show #NA!
    SplitArray = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo FunctionErred
    'Split the array
    If Left(Text, 1) = "{" And Right(Text, 1) = "}" Then
        SplitArray = Split(Replace(Mid(Text, 2, Len(Text) - 2), """", ""), ",")
    Else
        SplitArray = Text
    End If
FunctionErred:
End Function
```

Giving

```vb
=SUM(COUNTIFS('sheet1'!$D$2:$D$838,"<>NA",'sheet1'!$E$2:$E$838,SplitArray(A1)))
```

Comment: actually the code is in c# where direct excel formula has been used

Comment: @user3471438 Then use the `SUMPRODUCT` version, which is entirely Excel Formula